# Why is such a short code in tkinter so horribly slow?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a Python beginner and currently learning to create a unit conversion program. I'm not sure where the issue is, but this program runs incredibly slowly.
*By "slowly" I mean, I click on entry, and it doesn't respond. If I keep clicking multiple times, it takes about 8-15 seconds to confirm the click and allow me to enter.
*Sometimes it's slowly once it's running, sometimes it's not slowly when it's first running, and clicking on the entry works fine. But once a different unit is selected from the drop down menu, it starts to get slow.
Here is my code - just building the entries and dropdowns. function part hasn't been finished yet:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

entries_dict = {}
for row in range(6):
    for column in range(2):
        key = (row, column)
        entries_dict[key] = Entry(root, width =10)
        entries_dict[key].grid(row=row, column=column * 3)
        if column == 1:
            entries_dict[key].config(state="readonly")

unitg = ["g", "mg", "ug", "ng"]
unitL = ["L", "mL", "uL", "nL"]
unitmol = ["mol", "mmol", "umol", "nmol"]
unitgL = ["g/L", "g/mL", "g/uL", "g/nL",
          "mg/L", "mg/mL", "mg/uL", "mg/nL",
          "ug/L", "ug/mL", "ug/uL", "ug/nL",
          "ng/L", "ng/mL", "ng/uL", "ng/nL"]
unitmolL = ["mol/L", "mol/mL", "mol/uL", "mol/nL",
            "mmol/L", "mmol/mL", "mmol/uL", "mmol/nL",
            "umol/L", "umol/mL", "umol/uL", "umol/nL",
            "nmol/L", "nmol/mL", "nmol/uL", "nmol/nL"]
unitgmol = ["g/mol", "g/mmol", "g/umol", "g/nmol", 
            "mg/mol", "mg/mmol", "mg/umol", "mg/nmol",
            "ug/mol", "ug/mmol", "ug/umol", "ug/nmol",
            "ng/mol", "ng/mmol", "ng/umol", "ng/nmol"]
unitcollection = [unitg, unitL, unitmol, unitgL, unitmolL, unitgmol]

var_dict = {}
for row, units in enumerate(unitcollection):
    for column in [1, 4]:
        key = (row, column)
        var_dict[key] = StringVar(root)
        var_dict[key].set(units[0] if column == 1 else units[1])
        dropdownvar = OptionMenu(root, var_dict[key], *units)
        dropdownvar["menu"].config(bg="gray")
        dropdownvar.config(width=5)
        dropdownvar.grid(row=row, column=column)

for row in range(6):
    label_equal = Label(root, text = "=", width = 5)
    label_equal.grid(row=row, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

I've just been learning for a month and am frustrated with this problem. If you could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it！
*Tried both pycharm and IDLE, same slowdown.

Comment: Allow you to enter what?  I don't see that you have any functions here responding to clicks of any kind.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The main thing in this code is the entry and dropdown. after running it, when I want to enter something into the entry - it's slow, I click on the entry hundreds of times before it switches to the specified entry. when I click on the dropdown, it's slow - -the menu pulls down only after I click on it hundreds of times.

Comment: What are you running this on?  Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: The code works fine for me on a mac mini.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I am using PyCharm. When I noticed that it was not running properly, I switched to IDLE, but it was slow there as well. I am using a MacBook Pro

Comment: In general, it's problematic to run GUI code inside an IDE that is already a GUI.  The event loops collide  Does it work if you launch it from a command line?

Comment: @TimRoberts [IDLE](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/idlelib) is made using `tkinter` so the event loops shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: BTW, not sure if this is related: there is always a warning after I upgraded to macOS 14, saying "WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES."

Comment: yes - this warning is probably related. Your code run just fine for me as well - it is certainly something related to your system - which is likely intercepting calls to pass the widgets signals. AFAIK Macs have to emulate X11 in order to run tkinter - that uses an extra network layer for all signals to run, and things like antiviruses may be intereceppting this extra layer traffic.

Comment: TL;DR:  search the internet for "tkinter super slow on mac"- if nothing else works, set-up a Linux VM which includes a X11 session in separate window - things should run fine inside that window.

Comment: Thank you to each and every one of you for your help! I solved this problem today after upgrading python from 3.11 to 3.12! Although that WARNING is still there, and I don't know if it's going to strike again in the future...but it WORKS now! I can continue learning, thanks guys!